# Store a Linked list or a transformed version (array)

Tags: linked-list, frontend, backend, store

I created a doubly Linked List, now I want to send it to my Backend and from there to my database. Should I store the whole linked list, or should I transform it from a linked list to smth like an array before sending to Backend?

What is the common approach?

Comment: the best way is to parse into an array, what language are you using

Comment: It is on the Frontend using typescript :)

Comment: you can provide the linked list code, to help you

Comment: You must create a function to save the list in string or in some type of primitive data, you must also create a function to convert from the primitive data to the doubly linked list